# How can I align the edges of a cut cylinder with another cylinder?

Tags: objects

So I have two cylinders, one is cut and one is not.

Here is the misaligned cylinder (That is cut at 45 degrees):

[image]

Is is possible to align those edges and make them straight again with the cylinder behind it?

Edit:

Kind of like this, where the green lines represent how I want the selected objects edges to be aligned with.

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It's not quite clear what you're asking.

Comment: You could turn on snapping (shift+tab) and move each vertex in the front cylinder so that it snaps to the other cylinder.

Comment: I added a screen shot of what I'm kind of imagining. I want to keep the objects separate, but the edges on the selected object are not straight and run at a diagonal. I was wondering if there was a way to align those lines with the green ones on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Select the vertices that you want to flatten, then scale it along the axis you want to flatten by 0.

In this case, scale along the y-axis by 0.

[image]

Comment: Hm I see. However, I wanted to keep the cut and not return it back to a cylinder.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: @WilliamTurner Ronikos' answer is the correct one, the cut won't be deleted. Try it, you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

With the focus being to keep the edges aligned on both pyramids, I would suggest you duplicate the original cylinder and then bend the face using proportional editing, which can be activated using O. I found spherical proportional editing to work the best.

[image]

Comment: I like .gifs btw...